# Escrever Diretorio atual em um arquivo de texto

Tags: batch, cmd, txt

Num programinha em batch eu tenho:

```
echo Date >c:\users\...\testecmd.txt
```

Escreve a data atual em um arquivo de texto.

Supondo que eu não sei onde é o diretório no qual o auto executável está, como faço pra que ele chame o ***Diretório atual***, no lugar de "***c:\users...\testecmd.txt***" e escrever este mesmo diretório, no lugar de ***Date*** ?

```
echo "c:\Diretorio\atual\" >c:\diretorio\atual\testecmd.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%CD%` é a variável de ambiente que contem o diretório atual. E se você quiser acessar um arquivo no diretório atual, você pode usar o `.`:

```
echo %CD% > .\testecmd.txt
```

O arquivo `testecmd.txt` será criado no diretório atual, e o seu conteudo será o nome completo do diretório atual da linha de comando.

Answer (score 0):

---

- Nem precisa dar o **`echo`** na variável **`%cd%`** para obter o diretório/pasta atual, use o **`cd`**.

---

> Tem comando  para fazer isso direto, use o comando **cd** (***Check 
>    Directory***), no bat/cmd ou na linha de comando, direto.
>
> ### `CD>.\testcmd.txt`

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **Obs.:**
>
> • *[comando: **`cd`** ] [operador: **`&`** ] [comentário: **`::`** ]*

```bat
             cd            &                :: exibir o caminho da pasta/diretório atual na tela
```

---

### `CD>.\testcmd.txt`

---

```bat
cd & :: exibir o caminho da pasta/diretório atual na tela
G:\SO_pt-BR\Q113666

cd>.\testcmd.txt & :: redireciona a saída para o arquivo testcmd.txt

cd | clip & :: copia/move a saída do comando cd para o seu clipboard (Crtl+C)
```

---